# Read related data - ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to display my ingredient when I click on detail, but it's not working.

But when you click on "Detail," it goes to a blank screen.

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get;}
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    
    public int QuantityOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public QuantityOfMeasure QuantityOfMeasure { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Details(int? id)
{
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var ingredients = _context.Recipes
                                    .Include(u => u.RecipeIngredient)
                                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Ingredient)
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

        if (ingredients == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(ingredients);
}
```

Is there a problem with my Details method? But when you click on "Detail," it goes to a blank screen.

Is there a problem with the Details method? In debugging mode, the recipe ingredient count is 0.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marcus, Your code works fine here in my project. Pls check your `RecipeIngredient` table in the database if it contains such related record when `RecipeId=id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repair it. Since my unit of measure and the quantity are both models nested inside the ingredient model, I had to dig deeper.lockquote

```
public IActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var ingredients = _context.Recipes.Include(u => u.RecipeIngredient)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.Ingredient.UnitOfMeasure).Include(y=>y.RecipeIngredient)
            .ThenInclude(v=>v.Ingredient.QuantityOfMeasure)
            .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id == id);
        if(ingredients == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(ingredients);
    }
```